# rails 5 search by has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have three models

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :project_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_skills
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_skills
end

class ProjectSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I want to create a search that finds all the projects that include a set of skills.

For example:

- project1 skills: java, ruby, html
- project2 skills: ruby, c++.

So, when I search for "ruby" my result should be project1 and project2.

Comment: What do you mean by search?

Comment: Ihar Drozdov, search method

Comment: Search in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
Project.joins(:skills).where(skills: { name: "c++" })
```

will return projects that have the "c++" skill.

```rb
Project.joins(:skills).where(skills: { name: ["c++", "ruby"] })
```

will return projects that have either "c++" or "ruby" skills, or both.

Comment: Yep, you're right @moveson. Edited to correct that.

Comment: it returns #<Skill::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f48adc1fe38>

Comment: ok, it's work. My error in view, i understood. I create like this: @porjects.each do |project|    project.skills end

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `includes` method, which allows ActiveRecord freedom to determine the most optimal way to join the tables. Also, this looks like a good candidate for a scope. I'm assuming the skills are named using the field `name`, but substitute for the field you actually use.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :project_skills

  scope :having_skill, -> (required_skill) { includes(:skills).where(skills: {name: required_skill}) }

end
```

Now you can do:

```
>> projects = Project.having_skill('ruby')
```

And get back an ActiveRecord Relation containing the result set.

Answer (score 0):

If full text search is what you mean, I recommend `solr` using `sunspot` as its rails client. You can read more about sunspot [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot).

If on the other hand, what you need is just fetching associations, then this is what I would do.

```
#considering params[:name] = 'ruby'  
# also considering you have a name field on skills table :) You can use the field you use to store skill name. 
skill = Skill.find_by_name(params[:name])
@projects = skill.projects 
# This is what you need to get projects corresponding a particular skill in a has many through association.
```

But for a very complex full text search, I would surely recommend `solr`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this type of attrubute-specific method is deprecated. I believe the preferred method is `find_by(name: params[:name])`.

Comment: well, you could always use `where(name: 'ruby')` instead. I guess the idea was to show how associations could be retrieved :)

Comment: `where` is different, as it returns an ActiveRecord Relation, whereas `find_by` (like the old `find_by_[attribute]` returns a single record (the first that matches the criteria).